# Sort/Group an Array by 2 different Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a grouped/sorted array based on its "Program" attribute which is great. But now I need to sort by a different attribute (Deliverable) inside of that grouping, is that possible? And if so how can I accomplish that?

Here is a picture of my table.
[image: Example Output]

See how it is organized by Program? Inside of the Program grouping, I want to also  sort/group based on the Deliverable item, since there will be way more than two within each Program. Also, if it isn't too much work I would also love to make those rows clickable (expand/collapse) so the table isn't 100 rows long once it is loaded.
Here is my expected output:

**Expected Result**

```
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| Program    | Deliverable          |  Date     |   Approved | Notes        | To                  |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| Program 1  |                                                                                    |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            | Monthly Status Report|                                                             |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 05/10/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 03/30/2020| No         | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            | Meeting Minutes      |                                                             |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 02/10/2010| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 03/30/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| Program 2  |                                                                                    |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            | Monthly Status Report|                                                             |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 05/10/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 03/30/2020| No         | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            | Meeting Minutes      |                                                             |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 02/10/2010| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            |                      | 03/30/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| example@example.com |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Here is my code:

```
.then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(objItems));
      console.log(objItems);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr colspan = "5"><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";
        
        var sortedObj = {}
        objItems.forEach(item => {
        var program = item.Program;
            delete(item.Program); //remove this line to keep the program in the item data
            if (!sortedObj[program]) {
                sortedObj[program] = [];
            }           
            sortedObj[program].push(item);
        });

    Object.keys(sortedObj).forEach(key => {
      tableContent += "<tr>";
      tableContent += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
      tableContent += "</tr>";
      sortedObj[key].forEach(obj => {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td> </td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Deliverable + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      });
    });
      $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
var sortedObj = {}
objItems.forEach(item => {
var program = item.Program;
var deliverable = item.Deliverable;
delete (item.Program); //remove this line to keep the program in the item data
delete (item.Deliverable); //remove this line to keep the deliverable in the item data
if(!sortedObj[program]){
sortedObj[program] = {};
}
if(!sortedObj[program][deliverable]){
sortedObj[program][deliverable] = [];
}
sortedObj[program][deliverable].push(item);
});
 
Object.keys(sortedObj).forEach((program, index) => {
tableContent += "<tr class='breakrow'>";
tableContent += "<td>" + program + "</td>";
tableContent += "</tr>";
Object.keys(sortedObj[program]).forEach((deliverable, index) => {
tableContent += "<tr class='datarow'>";
tableContent += "<td> </td>";
tableContent += "<td>" + deliverable + "</td>";
tableContent += "</tr>";
sortedObj[program][deliverable].forEach(obj => {
tableContent += "<tr class='subdatarow'>";
tableContent += "<td> </td>";
tableContent += "<td> </td>";
tableContent += "<td>" + obj.To + "</td>";
tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Date + "</td>";
tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Approved + "</td>";
tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Notes + "</td>";
tableContent += "</tr>";
});
});
});
      $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
      $('.datarow').hide();
    $('.subdatarow').hide();
 
      $('#deliverablesTable').on('click', 'tr.breakrow', function(){
      console.log('hello');
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow').slideToggle(200);
      });
      $(document).on('click','#deliverablesTable tr.datarow', function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow, tr.datarow').slideToggle(200);
      });
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the result that you have.

```
Object.keys(sortedObj).forEach(key => {
      tableContent += "<tr>";
      tableContent += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
      tableContent += "</tr>";
      sortedObj[key].sort((a,b)=>{
          if (a.Deliverable > b.Deliverable) return 1;
          if (a.Deliverable < b.Deliverable) return -1;
          return 0;
      }).forEach(obj => {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td> </td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Deliverable + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      });
    });
```

Comment: That sorts them alphabetically, I am sorry I guess I did not phrase my question correctly, I thought I did but I what I was trying to ask is to group it like what I added to my most recent edit, check it out

Comment: Is this even achievable what I am asking. No one can seem to figure it out, and it has been a weight on my shoulders trying to figure it out